# How to detect pocket mode in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to detect the pocket mode in android. But I didn't find any useful links for this.

Can we check whether a phone is in a `pocket-mode` or not in android programmatically?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: If you mean [doze mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-doze), there's a good number of questions here, and Android 7+ has [light doze mode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/platform_mgmt#doze-life) which includes pocket mode-like situations. Otherwise, you have to check specific device manufacturers' specs to see how to interact.

Comment: @KenY-N Not a Doze-mode, I just want to know whether the phone in a pocket or not.

Comment: ActivityRecognitionApi may work for you https://developers.google.com/location-context/activity-recognition/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by reading values from various sensors. However, the result will be approximate. I implemented pocket detection by using the Proximity sensor, Accelerometer and Light sensor.

Getting the current parameteres from the sensors (accelerometer, proximity and light sensors):

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        g = new float[3];
        g = event.values.clone();

        double norm_Of_g = Math.sqrt(g[0] * g[0] + g[1] * g[1] + g[2] * g[2]);

        g[0] = (float)(g[0] / norm_Of_g);
        g[1] = (float)(g[1] / norm_Of_g);
        g[2] = (float)(g[2] / norm_Of_g);

        inclination = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(g[2])));
        accReading.setText("XYZ: " + round(g[0]) + ",  " + round(g[1]) + ",  " + round(g[2]) + "  inc: " + inclination);
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        proximityReading.setText("Proximity Sensor Reading:" + String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        rp = event.values[0];
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        lightReading.setText("LIGHT: " + event.values[0]);
        rl = event.values[0];
    }
    if ((rp != -1) && (rl != -1) && (inclination != -1)) {
        main.detect(rp, rl, g, inclination);
    }
}
```

Then based on this data I decide whether or not the device is in a pocket:

```
public void detect(float prox, float light, float g[], int inc){
    if((prox<1)&&(light<2)&&(g[1]<-0.6)&&( (inc>75)||(inc<100))){
        pocket=1;
        //IN POCKET
    }
    if((prox>=1)&&(light>=2)&&(g[1]>=-0.7)){
        if(pocket==1){
            playSound();
            pocket=0;
        }
        //OUT OF POCKET
    }
```

}

Keep in mind that the detection isn't fully accurate.
Code: https://github.com/IvanLudvig/PocketSword
Blog post: https://ivanludvig.github.io/blog/2019/06/21/detecting-device-in-a-pocket-android.html